# Simple example for a closure

Tags: javascript

Can someone point to a simple example to understand closure in detail?

the below link http://www.kirupa.com/html5/closures_in_javascript.htm is not clear.

Thanks.

Comment: How about [MDN - closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: Maybe you want to explain what exactly is not clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following

```
var noun = 'Governor';

var foo = (function () {
    var bar = 'Hello';
    // A
    return function () {
        var baz = 'Blake';
        console.log(bar, noun, baz);
        // B
    };
}());
// C
foo();
```

- At *line A*, which identifiers are referencable? `noun`, `foo`, `bar`
- At *line B*, which identifiers are referencable? `noun`, `foo`, `bar`, `baz`
- At *line C*, which identifiers are referencable? `noun`, `foo`

Now go on to think, if only `noun`, `foo` are referenceable at *line C*, why are the values of `bar` and `baz` appearing when we `foo()`? More specifically, why is `bar` still there? It isn't even defined in the function we've assigned as `foo`.

```
// remember, `foo` looks like this (log it to check for yourself)
function () {
    var baz = 'Blake';
    console.log(bar, noun, baz); // `bar` used but _not defined here_
    // B
}
```

This is because `foo` is a *closure*. There are identifiers *"wrapped up"* inside it which continue to live on for as long as `foo` lives.

Answer (score 0):

A *closure* is a function that uses references from higher-level scopes.

For example:

```
// Sorrounding scope
var a = "hello world";

var func = function() {
    // Function scope
    var b = a + " !!!!";
};
```

See [Closure (computer programming) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) to learn more about what's a closure in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that defines the variable `number`, then defines a function that references that variable. The inner function keeps a reference to `number` even when the outer function has closed off. The variable is basically in a pocket universe now where only the inner function can see it.

```
(function(){
    var number = 0;
    window.count = function(){
        number = number + 1;
        console.log(number);
    };
})()

count();
// 1

count();
// 2

console.log(number);
// number is not defined
```